# Google map generated Java Script any dynamic loop

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-maps-api-3

Can anyone tell me the Google map generated Java Script any dynamically loop for each category items need to display the Google map icons in different colours. Also database table data value will change frequently.var list = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.CourierList)).

var marker = new google.maps.Marker

```
{ position: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
    map: map,
    title: 'Click me',
    icon: 'icons/yellow-dot.png',
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    draggable: false
}
```

Comment: var list = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.CourierList));
OUTPUT
var list = [{"Disabled":false,"Group":null,"Selected":false,"Text":" Bob-Ann169$ ","Value":null},{"Disabled":false,"Group":null,"Selected":false,"Text":" Brian-Pam4$ ","Value":null},{"Disabled":false,"Group":null,"Selected":false,"Text":" Ken-Greer126$ ","Value":null}];

Comment: Using this icons
icon: 'icons/yellow-dot.png',
icon: 'icons/green-dot.png',
icon: 'icons/blue-dot.png',

Comment: To get an answer, I suggest you edit the question. Many people do not read the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to display different icons for different data on the Maps. If that is what you mean, you can define a string variable in the beginning and based on conditions have different values for the string.

E.g. you have three items and want to display them in different colors,

Logic will be

```js
var iconString = null;

if (firstItem)
iconString = "icons/yellow-dot.png";
else if (secondItem)
iconString = "icons/blue-dot.png";
else if (thirdItem)
iconString = "icons/red-dot.png";
```

then when you define the marker, assign this string to the icon attribute

```js
var marker = new google.maps.Marker

{ position: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
    map: map,
    title: 'Click me',
    icon: iconString,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    draggable: false
}
```

Comment: This my list out put value
var list = [{"Disabled":false,"Group":null,"Selected":false,"Text":" Bob-Ann169$ ","Value":null},{"Disabled":false,"Group":null,"Selected":false,"Text":" Brian-Pam4$ ","Value":null},{"Disabled":false,"Group":null,"Selected":false,"Text":" Ken-Greer126$ ","Value":null}]
For example Bob-Ann169$,Brian-Pam4$ and Ken-Greer126$ same time display 3 colours

Comment: var list = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.CourierList));
var list = [{"Disabled":false,"Group":null,"Selected":false,"Text":" Bob-Ann169$ ","Value":null},{"Disabled":false,"Group":null,"Selected":false,"Text":" Brian-Pam4$ ","Value":null},{"Disabled":false,"Group":null,"Selected":false,"Text":" Ken-Greer126$ ","Value":null}]
Please tell me how break to following out put
Bob-Ann169$,Brian-Pam4$ and Ken-Greer126$ above code

Comment: for(var item in list)
{
if(item.Text == 'Bob-Ann169$')
iconString = 'icons/yellow-dot.png'; 
else if(item.Text == 'Brian-Pam4$')
iconString = 'icons/green-dot.png'; 
else if(item.Text == 'Ken-Greer126$')
iconString = 'icons/blue-dot.png'; 
}

I am not much of a master in Javascript but this should do the trick.

Comment: This are unique values. Text":" Bob-Ann169$
Text":" Brian-Pam4$
Text":" Ken-Greer126$

Comment: Hello RRB, thank you advice. Are there any way to write that line name('Bob-Ann169$')without hard code item.Text == 'Bob-Ann169$'? because next it will come different name.

Comment: Yes that is the exact reason why we use it. This is to differentiate the different data in the JSON.

Comment: Well, you can use the index during the loop in the condition

Comment: No I can't because this line 'items.Text. can't use Text attribute,